# Vue - use vuex instead of eventbus for calculations with nested data & components

Tags: vue.js, reference, vue-component, state, vuex

I have app when bind big JSON object into component, then some parts from this object into next components etc. - it's structure with many deep levels, but object is not copied, I use advantage that objects are passing by reference.

Components on the lowest level have fields like "price", "qty" etc. When user modifies them, I updated object and run recalculation using global eventbus - after recalculation is done, I also use eventbus to forceUpdate some components. For example parents of these with fields price/qt, to refresh "total" amounts in categories.

Now I move some code to vuex and consider also here. Think that recalculation after commit will be ok. The question is - how can I modify this big object using commit from children components? The problem is that commit must "know" what part of object has been modified (for example, one element inside one of many categories)... I can do it in other way, pass child and parent data in commit and update parent but... will it work? I also need reference to do this in proper way...

Maybe still use binding to pass elements, but call store action to only make recalculation (not sure, that provides automatic refreshes on all required modules).
Or maybe other, better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some problems with architecture. Main idea here is to have some container (smart) component, that is connedcted with store (vuex), and simple (stupid) components, that recieve data from props. Also you must divide your store into modules, so it'll be easy to maintain. This approach will allows you to modify exactly pieces of data you want.

Comment: It's possible, but can't imagine how make some things using vuex. For example, I have categories, inside posts, inside comments. I must use v-for to display all categories, then another to display every element from category.posts, then also v-for for every post.comments. 

Of course, category has separate component, post also, comment also.
And using v-for + binding is ok. 
It also can work with vuex, but what if I want to edit every elements? Every I mean cats, posts, comments - using binding + reference is bad solution?

Comment: Try not to produce v-for components with store binding. Vuex works on pub/sub method, so you will get many many many subscribers and that's bad for app work. And for your case, you could call action where you want, just make sure you pass correct data to that action. It's ok when some child component update more global piece of data in store. You could call action inside child, but then you will need store binding, or you colud emit event to container element and call vuex action from there

Comment: Yep, I know and I not binding store, but params - objects, so they passed by reference, I share data and don't waste memory. I call store actions / get data for store only for some additional, shared data. For example - in each post you have select with "Author" selection. Users list is global, in vuex and not binding, but components get it from store.